# How can I add .so files to an android library project using gradle 0.7+

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

Project structure:

App project --> depends on Library project

Library Project 
has a folder for the compiled jni libs

```
jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
```

And I've tried adding the following to the android element of the build.gradle as per the example app https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/2e1f7810edd76d92cee8d3e06bc4dec0c288adea/tests/ndkSanAngeles/build.gradle however android library projects do not support productFlavours and as such the assemble fails with "Could not find method productFlavors() for arguments [dghdhd] on project"

```
productFlavors {
    x86 {
        ndk {
            abiFilter "x86"
        }
    }
    arm {
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "armeabi"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to add ndk support to an android library project?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

In the end I didnt need to use product flavours.

For the library project I added the following:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
        }
    }        
}
```

The libs folder had a folder inside called "armeabi-v7a" and as this is my only target it worked a treat.

The ndk files (.so) are propagated into the android project that is using the android library project.

Comment: While trying to build an older project that only had an "armeabi" folder, the .so files were not found. Copying them into a "armeabi-v7a" folder solved the issue. Not sure why it wouldn't fall back on "armeabi" in that case, but that's Gradle!

Comment: Let me just clarify - if someone is using Android Studio with the experimental Gradle 2.5 there is the following syntax:

android.sources {
        main {
            jniLibs {
                source {
                    srcDirs 'libs'
                }
            }
        }
    }

Comment: @pents90 you saved me a day! "armeabi" folder not worked, so I changed it to "armeabi-v7a" it's worked! I really don't know why this happened.

Comment: Is there official doc for the place to put native libraries?

Comment: I am able to generate the x86_64 only not armeabi, armeabi-v7a, x86. Can you please help me in this

Comment: @nn0p I wonder aswell, been searching for this, but can't find any documentation anywhere. You can find it in the hello-libs android ndk example and in this answer. It could have been mentioned somewhere in the "Add C and C++ Code to Your Project" guide page on android developers.. but it isn't afaik

Comment: I can't edit my comment anymore, but I found something: http://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html . And if you then learn that groovy functions can be called without parenthesis it becomes more clear, at least to me.

Comment: where exactly was the libs dir? was it project/libs or project/app/libs or maybe project/app/src/main/libs?

Comment: This only helps if you are already building on a NDK based project. What if you want to pull the dependency?

Answer (score 13):

Example with new [android experimental gradle plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental).

---

Requirements:

- Android Studio 1.5+
- gradle-2.10
- gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha5

---

**1) You could simply put all shared native libraries in the *main / jniLibs* folder, by default.**

*Project structure*

root folder / android project

root folder / android_project / app / src / main / jniLibs / x86

root folder / android_project / app / src / main / jniLibs / armeabi-v7a

root folder / android_project / app / src / main / jniLibs / ...

Gradle will automatically upload them to the device.

Then you could load the library in an application.

```
static {
    System.loadLibrary("mylibrary");
}
```

---

**2) You could also put all shared native libraries in the custom location.**

Example with a path to the *bin / android / Debug* directory.

In that case you should manually set the libraries location in the *build.gradle* file.

*Project structure*

root folder / android project

root folder / bin / android / Debug / jniLibs / x86

root folder / bin / android / Debug / jniLibs / armeabi-v7a

root folder / bin / android / Debug / jniLibs / ...

*root folder / android_project / app / build.gradle*

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        sources {
            main {
                jni {
                    source {
                        srcDirs = []
                    }
                }

                jniLibs {
                    source {
                        srcDirs "/../../bin/android/Debug/jniLibs"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure this answers right anymore? I don't think jniLibs gets created in AS now?

Comment: Think the default is just app/libs now (but not 100% sure)

Answer (score 0):

According to this thread:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adt-dev/nQobKd2Gl_8

not being able to add .so files to library projects was a bug that was fixed in v0.8 of the plugin.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sadly it didnt help resolve my issue. The fix was more simple.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Android Studio 2.1, and I found that adding the sources or sourceSets entry to my build.gradle had no apparent effect.  Instead I found that I needed the following:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        ndk {
            moduleName "libmp3lame"
        }
    }
```