# mupdf include native lib gradle

Tags: android, gradle, mupdf

I am trying to include mupdf in my Android application.
I run the steps from http://dixitpatel.com/integrating-pdf-in-android-application/
without any problems. But when the app is starting it runs into the following error:

```
Process: app.main, PID: 9712
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/app.main-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmupdf.so"
            at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
            at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:989)(MuPDFCore.java:14)
```

The "libmupdf.so" File is placed in the lib folder and I am using Android Studio with gralde.

I hope anyone can help me with that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Put the .so files in lib/armeabi and lib/armeabi-v7a
- In the build.gradle add `jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']` to the existing source sets - see [How can I add .so files to an android library project using gradle 0.7+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255125/how-can-i-add-so-files-to-an-android-library-project-using-gradle-0-7) for more details.

Comment: I forgot the line in the gradle script. Thank you very much :-)