# How to add JNI Libraries in android studio project?

Tags: android, java-native-interface, webcam

I was fetched some sample code to create **WebCam** android application. When i import the project, android studio's gradle building got error and i can't able to run the application . Guide me the steps to add JNI Library to work in my android studio application.

I get the coding from this [link](https://bitbucket.org/droidperception/simplewebcam/downloads)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: pls can you explain it in briefly !!

Comment: Possible duplicate of *[How can I add .so files to an android library project using gradle 0.7+](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255125/how-can-i-add-so-files-to-an-android-library-project-using-gradle-0-7)*. If you use *experimental* plugin, look at this ***[comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21255125/how-can-i-add-so-files-to-an-android-library-project-using-gradle-0-7#comment51680311_22072984)*** by user [tochkov](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4621448/tochkov).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jni Files are suppose to be placed at jni folder in android studio.

Below is project structure in android studio

[image]

Comment: ya its created!! Thanks