# Progauard Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'. > Job failed, see logs for details

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, proguard, android-proguard

I need to enable Proguard in my app.
When I'm enabling it i.e. for debugging like this-

```
debug {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
```

I'm getting following error-

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForDebug'. > Job failed, see logs for details
```

I know there are so many questions asked for this but no solution was able to solve my problem.

The problem is not in the definition of proguard rules because if I comment whole "proguard-rules.pro" file, then also getting this error.

There are two more module projects in my application.

I'm using following gradle plugin-

```
'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
```

and gradle wrapper-

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
```

I have added `-dontwarn` for all libraries but I have jinLibs also. What should I do in proguard for jin libs?

What could be the reason for it? If anyone needs more information then you can ask.

Comment: If you want to enable progauard then set `minifyEnabled true`.

Comment: Can you please paste full stacktrace log.

Comment: @EktaBhawsar - I already have. Sorry I edited the question now.

Comment: When we enable progauard in app then progauard minified the code. So sometimes any lib or class will keep in progauard file. like --keep class ...

Comment: You said, "There are two more module projects in my application." This can cause this error so you can add progauard --dontwarn ...

Comment: @EktaBhawsar - For both modules, I have already added -dontwarn.
But I have jniLibs also and didn't do anything for that? Do I need to specify something for jniLibs also?

Comment: may be this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/22072984/5514789

Comment: @EktaBhawsar - The link is for how to add jniLibs in project.It's not telling what to do in proguard if we have .so files in project.