# Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.HashSet'

Tags: android, gradle, compilation, java-native-interface

I'm trying to open a source code of Plumble , I changed gradle wrapper distributionUrl to 4.4 and then this gradle error appeared

```
tasks.withType(Compile) { compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn copyNativeLibs }
```

I searched and figured out in gradle 4.4 "Compile" is undefined and I have to use JavaCompiler instead but then this error appeared

```
Could not find method jniDir() for arguments [C:\Users\NP\Desktop\Plumble-Legacy-master\build\native-libs] on task ':packageDebug' of type com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication.
```

so I replaced

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniDir new File(buildDir, 'native-libs')
}
```

to

```
tasks.withType(com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageApplication) { pkgTask ->
    pkgTask.jniFolders = new HashSet<File>()
    pkgTask.jniFolders.add(new File(projectDir, 'native-libs'))
}
```

but now there is a new error in gradle building :

```
Cannot cast object '[]' with class 'java.util.HashSet' to class 'org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection' due to: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Could not find matching constructor for: org.gradle.api.file.FileCollection()
```

does anybody know how can I fix this?
any help will be much appreciated

Comment: You probably inherited these scripts from a very old version of Android Studio. Today, Gradle will build and pack the native libraries for you. Or, if you have prebuilt libraries, [add their location to jniLibs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22072984/192373).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even I faced the issue. The solution that worked for me is 
1) Update the build script with the exact maven repo url. 
2) add apply plugin : maven to the script.

Comment: Can you please update your answer with some more details? I'm facing a similar issue with the above error.

Comment: @Shivani Add the exact url - "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2" and try a clean build. It should work. Worst case scenario, delete the project and restart in a new space in your IDE. Post an update if it worked.